# Database in C# and establish a connection

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, ado.net

OK. I'm a beginner programmer and I want use database to store my data (like a student fields), Then should I install a SQL Server Enterprise? SQL Express edition? SQLite? MySQL? or ...? which one?
I'm confused like hell. Then what's a LINQ? or ADO.Net? These are a kind of connection to above's(SQL Server, ...) or what?
And finally when I created a application with a database that stores data, End User who wants install my application must install a kind of database?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Database you can use anything you want. I like to use PostgreSql because is open source so don't have to pay for license, and have a very good spatial library. MySql is also opensource, but lack of powerfull tools like CTE or rank analytic functions like  `lead`.

Then Ado.net is how you connect to database to bring data to your C# apps, and LINQ is how you handle that data.

For end user probably will need install same database as you, unless you provide remote access to your database or configure a cloud data source by creating a webservice

Answer (score 0):

That depend what you need. Sqlite is fine if no more than one user is using it at this same time. But bd can be easily moved with application. Server type db is better for simultaneoulus operations from multiple users. Can be moved either or can be acessed from copy of your app. I would recommed doing homework to be honest as this I very generic question and there is plenty info about databases out there.